# Which Thrust-Reverser-Systems are used by which engines and aircraft?

Tags: thrust-reverser

## Thrust-Reverser-Systems

According to various sources, Thrust-Reverser-Systems can be classified as follows ( see e.g. [Bräunling's "Flugzeugtriebwerke"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-34539-5), [Rick's "Gasturbinen und Flugantriebe"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-79446-2), [Purdue AAE Propulsion's "Thrust Reversing"](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~propulsi/propulsion/jets/basics/reverse.html), Aviation StackExchange Questions [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/how-does-thrust-reversal-work-on-a-jet-engine-and-when-should-it-be-used), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cold-stream-thrust-reverser-and-a-conventional), [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7689/why-dont-planes-have-a-reverse-propeller-as-air-brakes), [4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/why-dont-most-fighters-have-thrust-reversers), [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/why-cant-most-jets-safely-use-reverse-thrust-while-airborne) and [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14597/how-much-thrust-can-the-thrust-reversers-create) ):

- **Beta Range Propeller**
  Alternative names: Beta Mode Propeller, Beta Operation Propeller

  - Engine Type(s): Piston-Prop or Turboprop with a Controllable-Pitch Propeller (CPP) / Variable-Pitch Propeller
  - Mode of Operation: The pitch of the propeller blades is changed such that the propeller pushes air forward instead of backward.
  - Specific Example: [Allison T56-A-15 on Lockheed C-130H Hercules](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Norway---Air/Lockheed-Martin-C-130J-30/2171546/M/)
- **Bucket Type Reverser**
  Alternative names: Bucket Door Reverser, Target (Type) System with External (Type) Doors, Clamshell Door Reverser, Post-Exit Thrust Reverser

  - Engine Type(s): Turbojet or Low-Bypass Turbofan or Mixed-Flow High-Bypass Turbofan
  - Controlling Mechanism: Hydraulic
  - Mode of Operation: Bucket-shaped doors are closed after the engine nozzle. These deflector doors redirect the exhaust air to flow towards the front of the airplane.
  - Specific Example: [Rolls-Royce Tay 620-15 on a Fokker 70](https://www.flickr.com/photos/picturejohn64/4295098175/in/gallery-48018541@N04-72157623570087434/)
- **Clamshell Door Reverser**
  Alternative names: Deflector Door Reverser, Pre-Exit Thrust Reverser

  - Engine Type(s): Turbojet or Low-Bypass Turbofan or Mixed-Flow High-Bypass Turbofan
  - Controlling Mechanism: Pneumatic
  - Mode of Operation: Similar to the Bucket Type Reverser. Distinction: The deflector doors are deployed before the engine nozzle (but after the last turbine stage).
  - Specific Example: [BMW/Rolls-Royce BR710 on a Gulfstream Aerospace G-V Gulfstream V](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Japan-Coast-Guard/Gulfstream-Aerospace-G-V/0625322/M/)
- **Cold Stream Reverser**

  - **Cold Stream Cascade Reverser**

    - Engine Type(s): High-Bypass Turbofan
    - Mode of Operation: The rear part of the nacelle (nacelle sleeve) slides back,

      1. which activates the Cascades (guide vanes) to redirect the (outer/secondary) bypass air to flow towards the front of the airplane and
      2. which pivots Blocker Doors to block the (outer/secondary) bypass air just after the Cascades so that the air cannot follow its usual flow direction.
    - Specific Example: [Rolls-Royce Trent 800 Series on a Boeing 777](https://www.flickr.com/photos/picturejohn64/4295096503/in/gallery-48018541@N04-72157623570087434/)
  - **Cold Stream Pivoting Doors Reverser**

    - Engine Type(s): High-Bypass Turbofan
    - Mode of Operation: The Pivoting Doors both to redirect the (outer/secondary) bypass air to flow towards the front of the airplane and block the usual flow path.
    - Specific Example: [CFM International CFM56-5C2/4 on an Airbus A340](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Airbus_A340-313E%2C_Finnair_JP7370785.jpg)

## Question

**Which Thrust-Reverser-Systems are used by which engines and aircraft?**
So far, I just used standard search engines (web and image) and the [Airliners.net Photo Search](http://www.airliners.net/search/), but here you have to trust the photographers that they correctly identified the aircraft and engine.
Is there maybe an (official) list that provides the thrust-reverser-system for engine-aircraft-combinations?
If no one has published data sheets with specific engines and the corresponding thrust-reverser-systems and of there is no databases which can be queried for the used thrust-reverser-system of a specific engine, I will accept such an answer.

*Note: Feel free to extend the above information and/or turn it into a wiki.*

Comment: As each type of aircraft can be powered by different engines with different types of thrust reversers, it depends less on the aircraft and more on the engines. For example, the B777 uses all these different engines depending on the model PW 4077
RR 877
GE90-77B  PW 4090
RR 895
GE90-94B  GE90-110B1
GE90-115B1  PW 4098
RR 892
GE90-92B/-94B  GE90-115B1                                                        You also somewhat answered your question in your answer.

Comment: This question is extremely broad. It should be edited to either focus on where to find the data, or asking for data on a specific engine type or class.